# Android listview arrayadapter sqlite

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Estoy intentando llenar un *listview* con unos datos de una tabla **sqlite** pero no se que estoy haciendo mal, aquí les dejo el código si alguien me puede colaborar, la instrucción esta al final en *btnconsultar*.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtCodigo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto1);
    txtNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto2);
    btnInsertar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
    btnConsultar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn2);
    txtResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    //Abrimos la base de datos 'DBUsuarios' en modo escritura
    final UsuariosSQLiteHelper usdbh = new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(this, "DBUsuarios", null, 1);
    db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();

    btnInsertar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Recuperamos los valores de los campos de texto
            String cod = txtCodigo.getText().toString();
            String nom = txtNombre.getText().toString();

            //Alternativa 1: método sqlExec()
            //String sql = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (codigo,nombre) VALUES ('" + cod + "','" + nom + "') ";
            //db.execSQL(sql);

            //Alternativa 2: método insert()
            ContentValues nuevoRegistro = new ContentValues();
            nuevoRegistro.put("codigo", cod);
            nuevoRegistro.put("nombre", nom);
            db.insert("Usuarios", null, nuevoRegistro);

            //Alternativa 1: método rawQuery()
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT codigo, nombre FROM Usuarios", null);

            //Alternativa 2: método delete()
            //String[] campos = new String[] {"codigo", "nombre"};
            //Cursor c = db.query("Usuarios", campos, null, null, null, null, null);

            //Recorremos los resultados para mostrarlos en pantalla
            txtResultado.setText("");
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                do {
                    cod = c.getString(0);
                    nom = c.getString(1);

                    txtResultado.append(" " + cod + "      " + nom + "\n");
                } while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    });

    btnConsultar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
            SQLiteDatabase db= usdbh.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor fila= db.rawQuery("select * from Usuarios",null);
            if(fila.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    items.add("codigo: "+fila.getString(0)+"\n"+
                              "nombre: "+fila.getString(1));
                }while (fila.moveToNext());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
            lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: cual es el problema ?

Comment: Hola me sale error en esta linea  ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);

Comment: ERROR: Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, int, java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)

Comment: el problema esta en el this , proba poner MainActivity.this  (o el nombre de tu clase.this), es el contexto

Comment: Ok voy a probar

Comment: SI funciono !  Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en la inicializacion del ArrayAdapter, el contexto this no esta funcionando, hay que cambiarlo por el nombre de la clase por ejemplo

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(tuclase.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
```

Algo a tener en cuenta es usar `notifyDataSetChanged()` cuando necesites notificarle a la lista que actualize con datos nuevos de sql, entonces cuando cargues cosas nuevas solo llamas a

```
adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Entonces la lista se actualizaria con los datos nuevos y no tendrias que volver a llamar o re abrir tu app para que cargue el adaptador con los nuevos datos.